# How do you version control a built React project?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, production

Version controlling a dev build of React seems pretty straight forward. But when you run

```
npm run build
```

on a React dev build you get a "build" output that you use in the actual production. How do you version control this built React app?

Do you delete this build and replace with a new build for each version of your app? This doesn't seem safe for a prod build.

Comment: Yes, you rebuild each time, otherwise you'd still have the old build. There are artifact repositories if you want to store the build outputs, or you can rely on the versioned source code and a (hopefully) reproducible build process.

Comment: Which part doesn't seem safe to you?

Comment: So on a production server you would just delete the old build folder and upload the new one?

Comment: idk deleting the entire project from a server makes me hesitate @azium

Comment: don't delete it then? rename it to `app-backup` so you can rollback quickly?

Comment: Ah I see, I was just trying to see if you somehow integrated an old build to a new one, but it seems you just replace it.

Comment: Well, not quite, I'd have some kind of CI/CD pipeline, probably targeting some kind of application-layer abstraction over the infrastructure (think Heroku, Cloud Foundry), probably with blue-green or canary deploys and smoke testing, but in essence: yes, replacing the old app with the new build. You'd still have access to the old code (in version control) and/or build outputs (in an artifact repo) in case a rollback proved necessary.

Comment: Thanks cleared things up!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using `git` to version control your project:

Add build folder to your gitignore, so that git doesn't care about build folder, simply ignores it.

The logic is that anyone who builds is expected to get the same build folder created. So, no need for a version control system to keep watching it.

Comment: can you elaborate, Im not sure I understand

Comment: @iqbal125 this is a very essential question and everyone just ignores /build folder. There is not much controversy on this solution.